# JQ to flatten an array into an object

Tags: arrays, json, jq

I'm having trouble using JQ in what should be a simple task.

Here's a sample JSON:

```
[
    {
        "title": "channel 1",
        "url": "rtsp://thelink"
    },
    {
        "title": "channel UFO",
        "url": "rtsp://thatlink"
    },
    {
        "title": "channel oreo",
        "url": "rtsp://thatotherlink"
    },
    {
        "title": "channel blabla",
        "url": "rtsp://yetanotherlink"
    },
    {
        "title": "channel potato",
        "url": "rtsp://anotherlinkwhatnow"
    }
]
```

I'm attempting to flatten the array into a larger one for easier parsing later on low power devices. Here's what it should look like:

```
{
    "channel 1": "rtsp://thelink",
    "channel UFO": "rtsp://thatlink",
    "channel oreo": "rtsp://thatotherlink",
    "channel blabla": "rtsp://yetanotherlink",
    "channel potato": "rtsp://anotherlinkwhatnow"
}
```

I won't even pretend to understand the full structure of how JSON works, but with each little problem of this type solved, I come closer to understanding.

Any help appreciated. FWIW, being proficient in PHP I can very simply iterate with a `foreach` and recreate the new one with each value as a key. But I really wish to better understand how JQ works (not for lack of trying or reading the manual!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map` to map the array of objects to key-value pairs based on the fields you're interested in, then `add` to merge these pairs into an object.

```
$ jq 'map({(.title): .url}) | add' test.json
{
  "channel 1": "rtsp://thelink",
  "channel UFO": "rtsp://thatlink",
  "channel oreo": "rtsp://thatotherlink",
  "channel blabla": "rtsp://yetanotherlink",
  "channel potato": "rtsp://anotherlinkwhatnow"
}
```

Comment: works in concept, but the channel names don't all follow numeric increments, how would you go about actually using the key from the title ?

Comment: Well, that won't work given your example because keys must be unique so your result output will only have two keys, `channel 1` and `channel 2`.

Comment: my bad just realized the mistake, thanks. Edited the question to better reflect the sample

Comment: `jq 'map({(.title): .url}) | add'` then?

Comment: that was too easy for me to not be ashamed lol. so why no need for to_entries anymore?

Comment: Because you don't need index numbers in the new specification.